# Does ImageList_DrawIndirect with fState = ILS_ALPHA works on Windows XP?

Tags: windows, winapi, windows-xp, transparency, imagelist

We need to draw partially transparent images from a WinAPI imagelist.

`ImageList_DrawIndirect()` with ILS_ALPHA works fine in Win7, but doesn't work in Windows XP - the transparent regions of the icon are grey.

The result looks like this:

[image]

Comment: I added a screenshot because I suspect you aren't able to because you don't have enough reputation yet!

Comment: According to MSDN `ILS_ALPHA` is supported on XP. The problem is probably the surface on which you are drawing.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like your application isn't using version 6 of CommCtl32.  Normally, you need to include a manifest in your application to let it use version 6.

[Details at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773175%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) ...